# Quartz cluster - @DisallowConcurrentExecution avoid parallel run across instances

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have springBoot application running Quarts (2.3.0) with **cluster mode true** in multiple instances.

and I have configured job and provided delay of 2 seconds between each run.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {


  @Bean
  public JobDetail jobDetail() {
    return JobBuilder.newJob()
            .ofType(BatchTriggerJob.class)
            .storeDurably()
            .withIdentity("SCHEDULER")
            .withDescription("event")
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Trigger trigger() {
    return TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .forJob(jobDetail())
            .withIdentity("BATCH")
            .withDescription("SCHEDULER")
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().repeatForever().withIntervalInSeconds(2)
                    .withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
            .build();
  }

}
```

I have enabled DisallowConcurrentExecution

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class BatchTriggerJob extends QuartzJobBean {

  @Autowired
  private SchedulerService schedulerService;

  @Override
  protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    schedulerService.processBatch(); //business logic and may take more than 2 sec
  }

}
```

application.yml

```
quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceName: EVENT_SCHEDULER
            instanceId: AUTO
          jobStore:
            isClustered: true
            misfireThreshold: 60000
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
            tablePrefix: QRTZ_
          threadPool:
            threadCount: 1
```

However if job processing time is more than 2 seconds then another instance will start job execution.

I want sequential execution across instances with cluster mode on and only start another job across instance if current job finished in another of the instance.

**PS:** with single node even-if delay is < than processing time. job is running sequential due to @DisallowConcurrentExecution

Comment: in spring boot extending  BatchTriggerJob  with MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.StatefulMethodInvokingJob  has helped and made job stateful and non-Concurrent across instance. so now no parallel run if job processing time is more than delay

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible reasons why Quartz might ignore `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`

- Quartz property `org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered` is not set to `true`.

  `true` is not a default in Spring-Boot!
  You must provide this quartz property. For example, through application.properties:

  ```
  spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
  ```
- If you create the job through the standard Spring integration, the metadata will be stored only once in QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS. If you add the annotation later, the `IS_NONCONCURRENT` will not be updated.